# Judas in heaven

Tags: judas-iscariot

Question regarding Judas Iscariot.  Judas was a Jew by both religion and ethnicity, which would qualify him as one of the chosen.  Can we therefore expect to see Judas in heaven?  Thanks for your response and insight.

Comment: You did not mention anything about guaranteed salvation for the Jews in your question, which itself is another topic. How are we to know what you actually intended to ask? We all simply answered based on popular views regarding Judas' fate.

Comment: We are ultimately seeking to determine who the "Israel" in Rom. 11:26 is referring to.  Does "Israel" in that verse include the orthodox, i.e. Christ-rejecting, Jew?  If so, then Judas, as such a Jew, is guaranteed, by that verse, to be saved.  But if it refers to only believers in Christ, i.e. the church comprised of believing Gentiles and Messianic Jews; then the orthodox Christ-rejecting Jew is clearly excluded; and to claim that such a Jew is somehow still "chosen" is clearly anti-scriptural.

Comment: If Judas is in heaven, it would be hard to understand why it would have been better if he had never been born.

Answer (score 2):

**Is Judas in Heaven?** We don't know.

**What are the chances that Judas is in Hell?** Very high because of these verses.

> The Son of Man will go just as it is written about him. But woe to
>   that man who betrays the Son of Man! It would be better for him if he
>   had not been born." *(Matthew 26:24, NIV)*
>
> While I was with them, I protected them and kept them safe by that
>   name you gave me. None has been lost except the one doomed to
>   destruction so that Scripture would be fulfilled.
>   *(John 17:12, NIV)*

**Wasn't Judas elected as the Apostle by Jesus Himself?** Yes, but Jesus knew that Judas would betray him.

> Then Jesus replied, "Have I not chosen you, the Twelve? Yet one of you
>   is a devil!"  *(John 6:70, NIV)*

Though Judas might have performed miracles in the name of Jesus, it doesn't guarantee that he was a true disciple.

> Many will say to me on that day, ‘Lord, Lord, did we not prophesy in
>   your name and in your name drive out demons and in your name perform
>   many miracles?’ Then I will tell them plainly, ‘I never knew you. Away
>   from me, you evildoers!’ *(Matthew 7:22-23, NIV)*

**What is the possibility that Judas is in Heaven?** Let God be the judge.

God knows what was in the heart of Judas, why he betrayed his master and what was going on in his mind when he returned the 30 pieces of silver and why. Nevertheless, there is possibility that Judas might be in Heaven if he repented just before he died, which was the same case for the repentant thief crucified at the right side of Jesus.

**UPDATE:**

**Will Judas go to Heaven because he was a Jew?** NO. Judas can be saved only if he truely repented and accepted Jesus as the Messiah. We cannot find strong evidence in the Bible  that Judas actually believed Jesus as the Messiah. Jesus is the only way to Heaven and unless you believe in Him, you cannot go to Heaven. There is no difference between Jew or Gentile. All are under the same judgement, we will be judged based only on what we have done with Jesus Christ in our lifetime. [Being a Jew doesn't guarantee any salvation](http://www.gotquestions.org/Jews-saved.html).

> For there is no difference between Jew and Gentile—the same Lord is
>   Lord of all and richly blesses all who call on him (Romans 10:12, NIV)

Comment: The answer is yet to tackle *Judas was a Jew by both religion and ethnicity*

Comment: You're right, FMShyanguya, no one's tackled that yet.

Deepu, I concur fully. But dispensational doctrine claims that, based on selected OT passages and selected verses in Romans 11 (e.g. v. 1-2; 26), the Jew is virtually guaranteed salvation. John Hagee, Jack Van Impe, David Jeremiah, and a multitude of others make such claims. Therefore, from the dispensational perspective, Judas would be guaranteed salvation.

Perhaps someone of the dispensational persuasion could comment?

Comment: @Mawia Good answer. Thank you for the update.

Comment: Judas truly repented, and it happen in hell, when Judas saw Jesus in hell preaching the gospel of salvation, offering the infinite mercy of God. If you were Judas, will you accept it? Yes!, Judas said, "My Lord and my God, you are indeed the Messiah, please forgive and save me..". And Jesus answered, you are my friend, and I lay down my life for all my friends. -John15:13

Answer (score 0):

The prospect of Judas Iscariot entering heaven is very slim.

The following scriptures can be taken as evidence for his probable eternal damnation. John 6:71-72 says

> Jesus answered them: Have not I chosen you twelve; and one of you is a devil? Now he meant Judas Iscariot, the son of Simon: for this same was about to betray him whereas he was one of the twelve.

Here Jesus himself acknowledged the fact that Judas was not a man of God.
Luke 22:36 says

> And Satan entered into Judas, who was surnamed Iscariot, one of the twelve. And he went, and discoursed with the chief priests and the magistrates, how he might betray him to them. And they were glad, and convenanted to give him money. And he promised. And he sought opportunity to betray him in the absence of the multitude

. This clearly suggests that Judas was taken over by Devil. And then finally he committed suicide after betraying Christ without waiting for his eternal mercy to redeem him. So if we think in a conventional sense it can be expected that Judas will not enter Heaven.

But after all who can pass a judgement? God in his infinite mercy might allow any one to enter heaven and be united with him.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Interesting.  So Judas' Jewishness was/is of no avail?  Yet we're told that all Israel will be saved.  Why did/does that not include Judas?  He met the criteria of Jewishness.  Might Judas' fate apply to other Jews as well?

Comment: Jewishness doesn't matter. Matthew 3:9 says "And do not think you can say to yourselves, 'We have Abraham as our father.' I tell you that out of these stones God can raise up children for Abraham"

Comment: This needs some kind of paragraph break so bad.

Answer (score 0):

**Opening**

From [the answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31069/why-can-the-church-declare-a-person-a-saint-but-not-state-that-they-are-damned/31072#31072) to this question - *Why can the Church declare a person a saint but not state that they are damned?* - we learned that the Church, and no one in the Church can declare definitively that someone is in hell.

---

**Answering**

Focusing in on the question, *'Is Judas in heaven?'*

The Church has not and cannot say that he [or anyone else] is in hell, but from the words of the Lord himself, his Apostle Peter, and scripture, it is highly unlikely that he is in heaven.

> [Mt 26:24
>   (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+26%3A24&version=RSVCE)
>   24 The Son of man goes as it is written of him, but woe to that man by
>   whom the Son of man is betrayed! **It would have been better for that
>   man if he had not been born**.”
>
> [Jn 17:12
>   (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+17%3A12&version=RSVCE)
>   12 While I was with them, I kept them in thy name, which thou hast
>   given me; I have guarded them, **and none of them is lost but the son of
>   perdition**, that the scripture might be fulfilled.
>
> [Ac 1:20
>   (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+1%3A20&version=RSVCE)
>   20 For it is written in the book of Psalms,
>
> ‘**Let his habitation become desolate**, and let there be no one to live
>   in it’; and
>
> ‘His office let another take.’

... that word *'desolate'* ...

---

In addition to the passage in [Deepu's answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32398/judas-in-heaven/32401#32401), from [Heb 4:1-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews+4%3A1-11&version=RSVCE), it should be clear that just belonging to Israel or to the Church for that matter is not in itself enough to enter into God's definitive rest which is heaven.

---

**Closing**

An exorcist has run into *'Judas'* or a supernatural entity claiming to be Judas. [cf. [The Entire Case History of Anna Ecklund: America’s Most Famous Case of Possession](http://diabolicalconfusions.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/the-entire-case-history-of-anna-ecklund-americas-most-famous-case-of-possession/#more-233)].

Comment: Judas did not betray Jesus as the "Son of Man", Judas only look upon Jesus as "Rabbi" and not the Son of Man, and so, that passage does not apply to Judas.