# How do we know the Saints, the Righteous and the Holy Ones are alive and in heaven?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, intercession, intercession-of-saints

Why should Catholics ask the Saints and Mother Mary to take our prayers to God for us? How does the Catholic church know they can canonize "Saints"? How do we know the angels and saints will intercede our prayers for us, as to get Gods priority attention. Is asking for intercession better than just praying directly to God?

Comment: Short answer:  We don't.  We reasonably assume.

Comment: You're asking a whole lot of questions here. Maybe narrow down your question to just 1? Though I think you'll find that each of these is a duplicate of an already existing question.

Comment: @HeidiLundSolokis Welcome to the site! And this one deals with canonization: [Why can the Church declare a person a saint but not state that they are damned?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31069/why-can-the-church-declare-a-person-a-saint-but-not-state-that-they-are-damned).

Comment: @FMShyanguya Your title edit was fine, but using the post space to address comments and commenters, specifically, is inappropriate. It is discouraged even on your own posts.

Comment: @fredsbend Thank you for the education! Just thinking of a way to assist *HeidiLundSolokis* ask the question she wants to ask ...

Comment: You have asked several questions, some of which, no doubt, already have answers here. Can you narrow your question to a single question? Feel free to ask multiple questions in multiple posts if you wish.

Comment: This is really about 4 different questions rolled into one. The first and primary one is already duplicated two other places on the site. It looks like the one about the canonization of Saints might be too. Can we get you to ask individual questions for each point here than has not been directly asked already? Thanks!

Comment: @Calvin: If you're a Christian, you have to believe in the immortality of the soul. If you're not, there are still philosophical arguments for the immortality of the soul.